# How to disable ip https validation in the ios simulator?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ios-simulator

I am creating an ios webview using Ionic 4. I have already built the ios platform and I am testing on xcode with the iphone XR-12 simulator.
My application calls an iframe to an ip https test with a self-signed certificate.
The problem is that ios does not allow me to access this ip because it is self-signed. 
I'm calling this server with iframe and also use web service that access it from httpclient ionic. I cant access to server.

I have already tried adding the exception using NSAppTransportSecurity

```
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>MI IP</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

But in a forum I read that it doesn't work with ip and that I need a domain like www.example.com

So I tried to modify the host file but I would have to change all redirects and the css and links do not work correctly
so I ruled out this possibility of editing the hosts
Also try installing the certificates in the simulator. I was dragging the certificate to the simulator and install it and also activate it in certificate trust settings. But it does not work

Already try adding this code in AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}
```

Also try adding this code in CDVWKWebViewEngine.m

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge
                                   *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)
                                                                  (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition
                                                                   disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,
                      [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust]);
}
```

Also add this in config.xml

```
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine"/>
```

But nothing works

In the logs from simulator ios

Task <837DAB71-F2D7-46C1-A29A-D1AD6736493F>.<2> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “IP WEB SITE” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    ""
), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://IP WEB:4430/domesticas3p/registro, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://WEB IP/domesticas3p/registro, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa1a8e15650 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9843, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9843, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCer []

And dont show nothing in the place where is the iframe and the sime proble calling to web service

Sorry my english, and thank you your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your `.plist` file has it backwards. You first disable ATS by setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `true` and then creating an exception for your IP which disallows insecure loads from this IP.

Also note the correct setting should be `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` not `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPSLoads`.

Change your `.plist` file in the following way:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>your.ip.or.domain</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

This will keep ATS switched on and just disables it for your single IP or domain.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the cdvwkWebViewEngine.m and added this code, 
It worked for me, 
Thank you

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
  didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
  completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {
  SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
  completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust]);

}